# How to get value textbox in datatable column jquery and push to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

[image]

I want to get a value of 53.54.57 but somehow I always get the value of 53.53.53 not as expected. anyone can help me?

```
   columns: [
      { data: 'linenum' },
      { data: 'nama' },
      { data: 'harga' },
      { data: 'qty' },
      { data: 'total' },
      { data: 'remove' },
      { data: 'untung' },
    ]

 $("#table-main").DataTable().rows().every(function(){
      var data = this.data();
      var master_id = $("#" + $(data.remove).attr("id")).val();
     
      //53,54,57 is index column name = "remove"
      var master_barang_id;
      master_barang_id = $("#" + $(data.remove).attr("id")).val(); //the method I use to retrieve data
      alert(master_barang_id); //it should alert 53,54,57 BUT alerts only appear 53,53.53
    });
```

$("#" + $(data.remove).attr("id")).val();
I use this function to retrieve data from the datatable, but the line can only be the same value. always a value of 53, how to get the value of a line in the column called 'remove'
Is my looping wrong? or is there another way to get that value?

Comment: It would help if you provide a demo that demonstrates this issue. We have no idea what value of `data.remove` is for each row, or how you render the various element IDs

Comment: It sounds like to me you are duplicating element ids, but that is just a guess without a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Like **@charlietfl** said, it seems you're duplicating the element ids.

If I understood you correctly, and the id of your input(type number) is the value, then you only need to change one line:

```
$("#table-main").DataTable().rows().every(function(){
  var data = this.data();
  var master_id = $("#" + $(data.remove).attr("id")).val();
 
  //53,54,57 is index column name = "remove"
  var master_barang_id;
  
  //change this line
  //master_barang_id = $("#" + $(data.remove).attr("id")).val(); //the method I use to retrieve data

  //for this one
  master_barang_id = $("#" + data.remove).val();
  alert(master_barang_id); //it should alert 53,54,57 BUT alerts only appear 53,53.53
});
```

This is a working example:

```js
var jsonData = [{ "linenum": 1, "nama": "lampu economat 3w LED", "harga": 20000, "qty": 1, "total": 20000, "remove": 53, "untung": "X" }, { "linenum": 2, "nama": "lampu economat 5w LED", "harga": 25000, "qty": 1, "total": 25000, "remove": 54, "untung": "X" }, { "linenum": 3, "nama": "lampu economat 9w LED", "harga": 30000, "qty": 1, "total": 30000, "remove": 57, "untung": "X" }];

$("#btnGetData").click(function() {
    
  $("#table-main").DataTable().rows().every(function(){
      var data = this.data();
      
      var master_id = $("#" + $(data.remove).attr("id")).val();
      
      //53,54,57 is index column name = "remove"
      var master_barang_id = $("#" + data.remove).val(); //the method I use to retrieve data
      alert(master_barang_id); //it should alert 53,54,57 BUT alerts only appear 53,53.53
    });
});

var oTable = $('#table-main').DataTable({
  data: jsonData,
  columns: [
      { data: 'linenum' },
      { data: 'nama' },
      { 
        data: 'harga',
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return '<input type="text" value=' + data + ' />';
                          }
      },
      { 
        data: 'qty',
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return '<input type="number" value=' + data + ' />';
                          }
      },
      { data: 'total' },
      { 
        data: 'remove',
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return '<input type="number" id="' + data + '" value=' + data + ' />';
                            }
      },
      { data: 'untung' },
  ]
});
```

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="data-table-container">
  <table id="table-main" class="table cell-border order-column stripe">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>linenum</th>
        <th>nama</th>
        <th>harga</th>
        <th>qty</th>
        <th>total</th>
        <th>remove</th>
        <th>untung</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnGetData" value="GET DATA" />
```